# Cassandra + Spark executor hyperconvergence

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

As Apache Spark is a suggested distributed processing engine for Cassandra, I know that there is a possibility to run Spark executors along with Cassandra nodes. 
My question is if the driver and Spark connector are smart enough to understand partitioning and shard allocation so data are processed in a hyper-converged manner.

Simply, does the executors read data stored from partitions that are hosted on nodes where an executor is running so no unnecessary data are transferred across the network as Spark does when it's run over HDFS?

Comment: Theoretically yes. however practically I have seen less of it on the cloud where separate nodes are used for spark and Cassandra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Spark Cassandra Connector is able to do this. From the [source code](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/CassandraTableScanRDD.scala#L50):

> The `getPreferredLocations` method tells Spark the preferred nodes to fetch a partition from, so that the data for the partition are at the same node the task was sent to. **If Cassandra nodes are collocated with Spark nodes, the queries are always sent to the Cassandra process running on the same node as the Spark Executor process, hence data are not transferred between nodes.** If a Cassandra node fails or gets overloaded during read, the queries are retried to a different node.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes. Same for HDFS too. Howevet practically I have seen less of it on the cloud where separate nodes are used for spark and Cassandra when their cloud services are used. If you use IAsAS and setup your own Cassandra and Spark then you can achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Alex's answer:

> Yes, Spark Cassandra Connector is able to do this. From the source
>   code:
>
> The getPreferredLocations method tells Spark the preferred nodes to
>   fetch a partition from, so that the data for the partition are at the
>   same node the task was sent to. If Cassandra nodes are collocated with
>   Spark nodes, the queries are always sent to the Cassandra process
>   running on the same node as the Spark Executor process, hence data are
>   not transferred between nodes. If a Cassandra node fails or gets
>   overloaded during read, the queries are retried to a different node.

That this is a bad behavior.

In Cassandra when you ask to get the data of a particular partition, only one node is accessed. Spark can actually access 3 nodes thanks to the replication. So without shuffeling you have 3 nodes participating in the job.

In Hadoop however, when you ask to get the data of a particular partition, usually all nodes in the cluster are accessed and then Spark uses all nodes in the cluster as executors.

So in case you have a 100 nodes: In Cassandra, Spark will take advantage of 3 nodes. In Hadoop, Spark will take advantage of a 100 nodes.

Cassandra is optimized for real-time operational systems, and therefore not optimized for analytics like data lakes.

Comment: Thanks for additional info. I don't intend to use Cassandra as a data lake solution. We are researching to use it as a real time HA operational data store (similar to Google BT), but I am searching for processing framework that can be used to do full-scans and range-scans to detect anomalies and do corrections. Spark is ideal candidate and I have been researching how efficient it can use partition colocation to eliminate unnecessary toil and IO operations.